# "He cooked me a soup with a lot of hot oil"

Tags: expressions, idioms, translation

I'm looking for an English equivalent to a Persian expression which means *this person got me in a lot of trouble*. Literally translated, the expression is *this person cooked a soup for me that had too much hot oil*.

Comment: This person got me in hot water.

Comment: Or "This person put me right in the soup."

Comment: I think we usually just say _he screwed me_, and don't bother with fancy metaphors.

Comment: I heard an interview with [Alan Eyre](https://soundcloud.com/theworld/washingtons-persian-language-spokesman-world-in-words-podcast), Washington's Persian-language spokesman. He said that Persian is full of fancy phrases like this, that's what he loves about it. English is not so evocative.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the phrase "in hot water" or "getting in hot water".

The phrase means getting in trouble or getting someone in trouble depending on how you use it.

The definition of **in hot water** is

> "In a difficult situation in which you are likely to be punished"

Source - thefreedictionary.com

Comment: It seems like the expression he's looking for should be specific to someone else putting you into the situation. You can get into hot water all by yourself.

Comment: Then: He got/put me in hot water.

Answer (score 0):

**lead astray**  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-lead-someone-astray)

> if you are led astray by someone or something, you behave badly
>   or foolishly because of them